# Scrolling <div> when the page moves up or when the scroll bar is moving down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` that I want to move down by just a few pixels when the page scrolls down. In what possible way can I do to make this happen? 
I can't find any demo for this so just think of this..
When the page loads, of course it shows from very top of the page, then for example, 200px starting from the top, is the navigation, then 100px from the navigation is a slider. What I want is, If the user scrolls the page, it will automatically show the slider.

`position: fixed;` is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't understand the behavior. What is the slider supposed to do if it only triggers _after_ you scroll?

Comment: the slider is just an example. it is just any kind of `<div>`. it is just a `<div>`

Comment: So the div is hidden, then when you scroll the div is displayed, but if you scroll past it it shouldn't stick to the viewport?

Comment: it is not hidden, but it shouldn't stick to the viewport. when I scroll down, the `<div>` will move a little down. but the `<div>` will not move up to the bottom that's why I didn't use the `position: fixed;`

Comment: I really don't understand what you want. How do you _"not move up to the bottom"_ the bottom is at the bottom, you move _down_. Right?